# CSS in Rails Javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a .js.erb file that replaces some html and erb code when a user signs in. In a particular li tag, I want to put some inline css. However, the javascript doesn't execute when I do that. Is there some kind of escape_css function that I need to include in order for me to have css in a javascript file? My code is below. Thanks.

**views/users/signinA.js.erb**

```
$("#signin").html("<%= j(link_to currentAdmin.name, currentAdmin)%>\
                   <ul>\
                       <li><%= j(link_to "Account", edit_admin_path(currentAdmin))%></li>\
                       <li style="width: 100px"><%= j(link_to "Sign Out", signout_path, method: :post, data: {remote: true})%></li>\
                   </ul>");
```

Comment: Just escape your double quotes around css rule like this: `\"width: 100px\"` or replace your double quotes with single quotes like this: `'width: 100px'`

Comment: Although that worked, I recommend you to put that into a partial and do something like `$("#signin").html("<%= j render(your_new_partial) %>");`

Comment: That makes sense too. I do that somewhere else in my code. Is there any difference other than it's "cleaner"?

Comment: It's cleaner, easier to read and not so error prone as the above. It is slower if you take into account you call render (but you're talking about some milliseconds)

Answer (score 0):

Could you use jquery to modify the css of the li element.

```
$('#id of li element").css("width", "100px");
```

or give that li a class and style it within your stylesheet.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't do anything. It worked when I called .attr(...), but then the page didn't update with the new style. @Octopus-Paul's method worked but thanks.